# Translations of formlabels FOSUserBundle's registration form don't get overriden but login form does

Tags: php, symfony

I have 2 forms on my page.
One is FOSUserBundle's login form and the other one's FOSUserBundle's registration form.

I would like to change some default values for the formlabels. 
For example I like to change "fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_first" like this

```
fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_first: "Password:"
```

I have this for my login form (in the same FOSUserBundle.en.yml file)

```
security:
    login:
        username: "Username"
        password: "Password"
        remember_me: Remember mee
        submit: Loginn
```

Why does the login form has the changed labels but the registration form doesn't? The only difference I see is that the registration form is rendered like

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

and the login form has each field rendered manually like:

```
<label for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>
```

// EDIT

I have overriden the RegistrationForm. Also, I've noticed that the form doesn't even show the labels as configured in the original FOSUserBundle.en.yml file. I see the label as "Username" whilst in the yml file it's been put as "Username:" (with the double point sign)

Comment: It doesn't work because you aren't explicitly asking to translate the registration form's labels like you did in the login form.

Comment: But I talked to someone on the symfony irc channel who renders the form like {{ form_widget(form) }} and his translations work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
There is a little form theming hack in form.html.twig in FOSUserBundle/Resources/Views that will call the trans function for every label. I just had to put this line in my overridden register_content.html.twig file

```
{% form_theme form theme %}
```